# Laravel collective form to normal html form

Tags: laravel

How can i make these two laravel collective form to normal html form

```
{!! Form::select('roles[]', $roles,[], array('class' => 'form-control','multiple')) !!}
```

```
{!! Form::select('roles[]', $roles,$userRole, array('class' => 'form-control','multiple')) !!}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? A select element in html looks like `<select>`...

Comment: View the page, view the source, copy

Comment: Just render the view and copy the source code.

Comment: I don't have laravel collective form installed . I am using larvel 6 and want to use it as normal html <select>

Answer (score 0):

Here would be a simplified example:

```
<form>
    <select name="roles[]" class="form-control" multiple>
        @foreach($roles as $role)
            <option value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</form
```

Comment: Thanks but what about the 2nd one it has another variable $userRole . It's for laravel spatie user role and permission system to add role to user